# Migrating from WebForms to MVC - Themes issue with common Master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, themes

I'm in the middle of migrating from an WebForms app to an MVC app.  Since this needs to be done over time, WebForms and MVC will live side-by-side with all new pages in MVC and we will slowly transition existing pages to MVC over time.

I want to continue to use the existing WebForms master pages in both WebForms and MVC (and am using the ASPX view engine as a result since it will allow me to specify a .master page).  The master page I am using doesn't use ViewState or PostBacks, so there should be no problem using it with MVC.

The issue is that the CSS is currently coming from the App_Themes.  There are 3 different themes that are used in the WebForms app today.  For the WebForms pages, the Page.Theme is set in the PageBase class (inherits from System.Web.UI.Page).  Since MVC doesn't use that mechanism (the Page class), How can I set the theme so the css is rendered correctly in the master page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested master page and apply your theme for the MVC part in the nested page. 
The nested page would just have one placeholder that fills a gap in the base master.

After that, just let all your MVC-views take from the nested page. This will assure that's not affecting the web forms, and it will still be applied to all your MVC pages.

(note: since MVC doesn't know anything about themes, you would need to add references to css-files manually)